# Using xmlns as a normal XML attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML that I'm parsing in C++ using pugi xml:

```
<root>

<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<tr>
  <td>Apples</td>
  <td>Bananas</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
<name>African Coffee Table</name>
<width>80</width>
<length>120</length>
</table>

</root>
```

In order to extract just the `table` element belonging to the `http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/` namespace, I thought I'd simply treat `xmlns` as an a regular XML attribute and try the following XPath: `/root/table[@xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']`. However, doing so returns 0 rows.

I'm able to retrieve the namespace as an attribute when I add a prefix to `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/` (eg `xmlns:htmlns`), so it seems like I can treat the `xmlns` attribute as a regular attribute to an extent. Can I only use `xmlns` as a normal attribute if there is a namespace prefix? What are the rules governing its use?

Comment: In what environment are you using XPath? The "proper" way to do this is declare a prefix in the environment and use it in your XPath expression. Also, can you explain what you mean by "This works"? Are you saying that `/root/table[@xmlns:htmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4']` returns non-zero results?

Comment: @LarsH I've edited the question. I'm parsing in C++ using Pugi XML, and I can retrieve `xmlns` as an attribute so long as it has an attached prefix. I don't think pugi xml is namespace aware unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, xmlns is not a useable as a regular attribute but there is an xpath function for that, try

```
/root/*[local-name() = 'table' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work when I try it with an online tool (http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) or when I try to do it in C++ using pugi XML.

Comment: This isn't correct.  You need to declare a prefix for the namespace then use `/root/html:table` ... assuming the prefix is `html`

Comment: @OP: The answer (before I edited it) didn't work with W3C-compliant XPath tools because the `table` name test with no prefix in XPath 1.0 means "an element named table that is in **no namespace**." But if you use `local-name()`, you can test against the element name without regard to the namespace.

Comment: @LarsH, @Stefan Hegny Your answer works, thank you. The only problem was that I left out the final `/` from the `xmlns` when I used it in my XPath expression above (it's in the original document but not in my XPath). So long as the final `/` is in the XPath it works. The answer should probably be updated to reflect that.

Comment: @Adam, as long as the final `/` is in the namespace URI in the XPath, what works? This answer? or your original XPath expression?

Comment: Thanks @LarsH and @DanielHaley!

Answer (score 2):

You either need to delcare a prefix the use that prefix in the xpath such as ...

```
xmlns=''
xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4' // I don't know how to do this with your library

/root/html:table
```

... or ...

You need to select all child elements and then filter on namespace such as this

```
/root/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']
```

Comment: From what I can tell, pugi XML isn't namespace aware like that. For you second suggestion, if I want to get all the `td` elements from the first table, would I have to use something like `/root/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']`? That would work in this case, but I could see things getting messy quickly with more complex XML. Ultimately, as far as I can tell there isn't really a good solution as long as I'm using pugi XML.

Comment: @OP: Did you look at http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#xpath.w3c? If you want all the `td` elements from the first table, you could just use `/root/table[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/']//td` (note the double slash) because pugixml only performs name tests on QNames. But yes, if you have more complex XML with closely intermixed namespaces, you could get into a mess with pugixml. And you will also be learning XPath wrong. :-) Which means that when you ask questions about "XPath" on SO, the answers won't match your tools.

Comment: really... that's a pretty big gap in XML.  I'd suggest you find a new library.

Comment: @LarsH: Is the QName of an element just the local name if the element in question belongs to the default namespace?

Comment: @Adam - Yes, the [QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-QName) of an element in a default namespace is just the local part (a QName can be either a prefixed name or an unprefixed name). The QName is not the same thing as the [expanded name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-expname) which would be helpful learning about.

Comment: @Adam: Usually, yes. The QName of an element is just the local name *if the element in question has no prefix*. But an element can belong to the default namespace while also having a prefix (whose namespace URI happens to be the same as the default namespace URI).